# Maximum of $x^2/(1.0001)^x$ over all positive real numbers.

Tags: calculus

Please check my math.  In

https://www.stewartcalculus.com/data/default/upfiles/LiesCalcAndCompTold.pdf   ,

the author claims (see exercise 3) that the maximum of
$$\frac{x^2}{\left(1.0001\right)^{\,x}}$$
over all positive real numbers is greater than $10^{124}.\ $  I think that the maximum is much closer to 54 million.

(If you want, I can write out the calculus, but I think that it will be more fun for you if you do it yourself.)

Comment: [Desmos certainly agrees with you at least.](https://i.imgur.com/sCzFp3A.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, as @K.defaoite already did, you consider
$$f(x)=x^2\,a^{-x}\qquad \text{with}\qquad a>1$$ the first derivative cancels at
$$x_*=\frac{2}{\log (a)}\quad \implies \quad f(x_*)=\frac{4}{\log ^2(a)}a^{-\frac{2}{\log (a)}}\quad \implies \quad f''(x_*)=-2 a^{-\frac{2}{\log (a)}}$$ So, $x_*$ corresponds to a maximum.

Expanding $f(x_*)$ as a series around $a=1$
$$f(x_*)=\frac{4}{e^2 (a-1)^2}\left(1+(a-1)+\frac{1}{12} (a-1)^2-\frac{1}{240} (a-1)^4+O\left((a-1)^5\right)   \right)$$

For your value of $a$, the above truncated series would give
$$\frac{2400240001999999999}{6000000000\, e^2}=5.41395\times 10^7$$ while the exact value is $\cdots$ the same.

Comment: Very nice.  I tried to compute the difference between the sum of the truncated series and the exact value and I got a difference of about $2\cdot 10^{-15}$.

Answer (score 3):

$$f(x)=x^2 a^{-x}\\ f'(x)=2xa^{-x} -x^2 a^{-x}\log a$$

Letting $f'(x)=0$,
$$2xa^{-x}=x^2 a^{-x}\log a \\ x=2/\log a$$

Letting $a=1.0001$ we get $x\approx 20~000.9999833$ and $f(20~000.9999833)\approx 5.4\cdot 10^{7}$.

Comment: Numerically it might be better not to compute $x$ but $f(2/\log a) = 4/(e \log a)^2$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $y = \frac{x^2}{\left(1.0001\right)^{x}}$.  Then:

$$\ln y = 2 \ln(x) - x \ln(1.0001)$$
$$\frac{1}{y} \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{2}{x} - \ln(1.0001)$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x^2}{\left(1.0001\right)^{x}} \left( \frac{2}{x} - \ln(1.0001) \right)$$

To find potential critical points, set the derivative equal to 0, to get:

$$\frac{x^2}{\left(1.0001\right)^{x}} = 0 \text{   or   } \frac{2}{x} - \ln(1.0001) = 0$$
$$x = 0 \text{   or   } x = \frac{2}{\ln(1.0001)} \approx 20000.99998333637$$

The former gives $y = 0$ (the minimum), and the latter gives $y = (\frac{2}{e\ln 1.0001})^2 \approx 54139526.75109822$ (the maximum).

So, you're correct, and the book is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The original exercise didn't restrict to the positive numbers, so the function has no maximum, and the supremum is $ \infty $ (approached at $ - \infty $), which is greater than $ 1 0 ^ { 1 2 4 } $.  But this isn't anything special about $ 1 0 ^ { 1 2 4 } $, so I doubt that this is what they were thinking.  Of course, you're right about the maximum of approximately $ 5 4 \cdot 1 0 ^ 6 $ when restricted to the positive numbers.

Comment: I did say "over all positive real numbers"   :)

Comment: That's right, you did.  But the exercise didn't.  So yet another error that you caught!